# How am I still seeing failed login attempts when denying all access to wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, wp-admin

I have limited access to my wordpress login page by adding the following `.htaccess` file to the `wp-admin` directory:

```
## due to brute force attacks, limiting access to specific ips
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 24.xxx.xxx.xxx 66.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I have had this in place for a day or three now and thought it was working.  But today I got a notice from our security plugin that this site has had several failed login attempts.  The failed login attempts were from an IP similar to this:

```
200.199.xxx.xxx
```

I am `x`ing out the IPs for security measures, but wanted to give you an idea of the IP families that I am allowing vs. seeing attempting login.

So how would it be possible for a bot or person to be able to even arrive at the login page with this type of blocking in place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So how would it be possible for a bot or person to be able to even arrive at the login page with this type of blocking in place?

No one needs to go to any “pages” to send requests to your server; they don’t even need to use a “browser.”

*Any* client that speaks HTTP can send whatever requests it wants to your site.

> But today I got a notice from our security plugin that this site has had several failed login attempts

The login form sends the data directly to `/wp-login.php` - that is not even in the `/wp-admin/` folder that you blocked access to.

`/wp-login.php` handles the complete login process, and only redirects to `/wp-admin/` afterwards.

The failed login attempts you see in your logs come from `/wp-login.php`

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. So should I use the same .htaccess limiting on the /wp-login.php page to block the unwanted traffic?

Comment: That would be a good idea, yeah. Otherwise someone could still succeed at logging in - they might not have access to anything within the /wp-admin/ path, but at least to user details exposed in the front end, and who knows what else maybe. If you want to go one step further, I'd maybe also  check the code of wp-login.php to see if it might redirect elsewhere, and also verify what routes get called during/after login via browser dev tools, network panel.

Comment: Plus, have you considered other attack vectors? What if I send requests containing an authentication cookie (however I might have gotten that, or maybe I try and brute-force it) to frontend routes outside of the realm you forbid outside access to? Pretty sure there's login checks going on there as well, without taking the route over wp-login or wp-admin. And once an attacker was logged in, what data would the frontend possibly expose? Hidden Posts, ...?